# aws s3 sync resulting in An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, botocore

So am trying to upload a big file 9G to s3 bucket which has no policy written and access opened to all (Objects can be public) and we have multiple aws accounts to switch and using below command am trying to upload certain artifacts to s3 bucket

```
aws s3 sync /media/sf_datadrive/ s3://xx-bucket/binaries --profile xx-prod
```

This is resulting in below error

```
upload failed: ../../media/sf_datadrive/prometheus/alertmanager-0.20.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz to s3://xxx-bucket/binaries/prometheus/alertmanager-0.20.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied
```

There is no bucket policy attached to the said bucket, should i add 1 ?

Comment: What S3 permissions does `xx-prod` have?

Comment: Are you able to upload files in other bucket using the same profile?

Comment: Hello thanks for your comments, I resolved it seems like I was not switched to AdminAccess rather trying it with ReadOnly access.